# Problem with Table of Contents, include sections/subsections

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to make an Index of my documents for all the section and subsection that I have, using `\tableofcontents` , but I don't understand why I have two problems...

I have this code in my index page

```
\newpage 
\tableofcontents
```

**First problem)** but this shows me only the title and the name of the author of the relation, and I don't want that these informations i my index, how can I fix it?

[image]

I don't want to see the text (title and authors) in the red circle...

---

**FIXED** Second problem)  I want to add my sections and subsections to the index, I read that I have to use under each section/subsection

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section/subsection}{name of section/subsection}
```

So, I added it under my Intro section like this

```
\newpage
\section{Intro}
\labelsec{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro}
```

But my `\tableofcontents` don't change and it only shows the title of my relation...
I read various questions about these problems, but no solution has solved my problem.

***Solution to second problem***:
I added `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` before the `\begin{document}`

THIS IS THE FULL CODE (without text in sections)

```
\documentclass{llncs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% package sillabazione italiana e uso lettere accentate
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{manifest}

\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem} %%per elenchi puntati

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%per numero di pagina

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% NUMERO DI PAGINA
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Relazione progetto di "Ingegneria dei Sistemi Software"}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

%%%%%%%
 \newif\ifpdf
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
 \pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
 \else
 \pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
 \pdftrue
 \fi
%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \else
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg, .tif}
 \else
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .jpg}
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\java}{\textsf{Java}}
\newcommand{\contact}{\emph{Contact}}
\newcommand{\corecl}{\texttt{corecl}}
\newcommand{\medcl}{\texttt{medcl}}
\newcommand{\msgcl}{\texttt{msgcl}}
\newcommand{\android}{\texttt{Android}}
\newcommand{\dsl}{\texttt{DSL}}
\newcommand{\jazz}{\texttt{Jazz}}
\newcommand{\rtc}{\texttt{RTC}}
\newcommand{\ide}{\texttt{Contact-ide}}
\newcommand{\xtext}{\texttt{XText}}
\newcommand{\xpand}{\texttt{Xpand}}
\newcommand{\xtend}{\texttt{Xtend}}
\newcommand{\pojo}{\texttt{POJO}}
\newcommand{\junit}{\texttt{JUnit}}

\newcommand{\action}[1]{\texttt{#1}\xspace}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\small{\texttt{#1}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\codescript}[1]{{\scriptsize{\texttt{#1}}}\xspace}

% Cross-referencing
\newcommand{\labelsec}[1]{\label{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xs}[1]{\sectionname~\ref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsp}[1]{\sectionname~\ref{sec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelssec}[1]{\label{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xss}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xssp}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{ssec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelsssec}[1]{\label{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsss}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsssp}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{sssec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelfig}[1]{\label{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\xf}[1]{\figurename~\ref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\xfp}[1]{\figurename~\ref{fig:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\labeltab}[1]{\label{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\xt}[1]{\tablename~\ref{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\xtp}[1]{\tablename~\ref{tab:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{tab:#1}}
% Category Names
\newcommand{\sectionname}{Section}
\newcommand{\subsectionname}{Subsection}
\newcommand{\sectionsname}{Sections}
\newcommand{\subsectionsname}{Subsections}
\newcommand{\secname}{\sectionname}
\newcommand{\ssecname}{\subsectionname}
\newcommand{\secsname}{\sectionsname}
\newcommand{\ssecsname}{\subsectionsname}
\newcommand{\onpagename}{on page}

\newcommand{\xauthA}{Nicola Casadei}
\newcommand{\xauthB}{Marco Benedetti}
\newcommand{\xauthC}{Erica Marchi}
\newcommand{\xauthD}{Mattia Ricci}
\newcommand{\xfaculty}{II Faculty Engineering and Informatic Science}
\newcommand{\xunibo}{Alma Mater Studiorum -- University of Bologna}
\newcommand{\xaddrCE}{via Sacchi 3}
\newcommand{\xcityCE}{47023 Cesena, Italy}

%
% Comments
%

%%% \newcommand{\todo}[1]{\bf{TODO:}\emph{#1}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


     \begin{document}

        \title{Esame finale A.A. 2016/2017\\
         Ingegneria dei Sistemi Software}

        %%% \author{\xauthA \and \xauthB}
        \author{\xauthA \\ \xauthB \\ \xauthC \\ \xauthD}

        \institute{%
        %%%  \xunibo\\\xaddrCE, \xcityCE\\\email{\{nameA.studentA, nameB.studentB\}@studio.unibo.it}
          \xunibo\\\xaddrCE, \xcityCE\\\email\ nameA.studentA@studio.unibo.it
        }

        \maketitle

        %==================INDEX
        \newpage 
        \tableofcontents

        \newpage
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \section{Intro}
        \labelsec{Intro}

        \section{Vision}
        \labelsec{Vision}

        ..... other sections

        \end{document}
```

If I have to add more code, tell me.
Thank in advance!

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just fragments only. Where is `\labelsec` coming from. And most likely you have to change the `tocdepth` counter value to 2 in order to see the subsections in the ToC

Comment: I added `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` and  `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} ` and the second problem is solved...

Comment: It is not the full code, it is still not compilable for us.

Comment: added more code, now it's compilable?

Comment: After removing `\usepackage{manifest}` it is compilable. And there some strange settings, most of which you would get more easily with `cleverref`, I think, but the main problem is `\maketitle` from `llncs` class. It adds the title to the ToC

Comment: the template, that include llncs class and maketitle, it's from my professor, so I don't know very well all the commands that he use in this template...

Comment: Templates are bad in 95% of all cases, written by people who glue things together just to get things 'working', but in fact, they ruin basically everything because they just don't have any knowledge of TeX or LaTeX etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\maketitle` from `llncs` class adds the title and author names to the `ToC` automatically.

This can be prevented by a redefinition of `\maketitle` (which is too long here) or a patching:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}



\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\authcount{\the\c@auco}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{author}{\toc@uthor}%
}{% Replace by 'nothing'
}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failed}}

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \if!\the\toctitle!\addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\@title}\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\the\toctitle}\fi
}{%
  % Replace by nothing
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed patching!}}
\makeatother
```

The code removes `\addcontentsline`... etc from the `\maketitle` command.

The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair is essential here, otherwise the patching would fail.

In addition, the 'template' is not very well designed, as is often the case with 'templates'.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% package sillabazione italiana e uso lettere accentate
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\usepackage{manifest}

\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem} %%per elenchi puntati

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%per numero di pagina

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% NUMERO DI PAGINA
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Relazione progetto di "Ingegneria dei Sistemi Software"}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

%%%%%%%
 \newif\ifpdf
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
 \pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
 \else
 \pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
 \pdftrue
 \fi
%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \else
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg, .tif}
 \else
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .jpg}
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\java}{\textsf{Java}}
\newcommand{\contact}{\emph{Contact}}
\newcommand{\corecl}{\texttt{corecl}}
\newcommand{\medcl}{\texttt{medcl}}
\newcommand{\msgcl}{\texttt{msgcl}}
\newcommand{\android}{\texttt{Android}}
\newcommand{\dsl}{\texttt{DSL}}
\newcommand{\jazz}{\texttt{Jazz}}
\newcommand{\rtc}{\texttt{RTC}}
\newcommand{\ide}{\texttt{Contact-ide}}
\newcommand{\xtext}{\texttt{XText}}
\newcommand{\xpand}{\texttt{Xpand}}
\newcommand{\xtend}{\texttt{Xtend}}
\newcommand{\pojo}{\texttt{POJO}}
\newcommand{\junit}{\texttt{JUnit}}

\newcommand{\action}[1]{\texttt{#1}\xspace}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\small{\texttt{#1}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\codescript}[1]{{\scriptsize{\texttt{#1}}}\xspace}

% Cross-referencing
\newcommand{\labelsec}[1]{\label{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xs}[1]{\sectionname~\ref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsp}[1]{\sectionname~\ref{sec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelssec}[1]{\label{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xss}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xssp}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{ssec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelsssec}[1]{\label{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsss}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsssp}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{sssec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelfig}[1]{\label{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\xf}[1]{\figurename~\ref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\xfp}[1]{\figurename~\ref{fig:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\labeltab}[1]{\label{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\xt}[1]{\tablename~\ref{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\xtp}[1]{\tablename~\ref{tab:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{tab:#1}}
% Category Names
\newcommand{\sectionname}{Section}
\newcommand{\subsectionname}{Subsection}
\newcommand{\sectionsname}{Sections}
\newcommand{\subsectionsname}{Subsections}
\newcommand{\secname}{\sectionname}
\newcommand{\ssecname}{\subsectionname}
\newcommand{\secsname}{\sectionsname}
\newcommand{\ssecsname}{\subsectionsname}
\newcommand{\onpagename}{on page}

\newcommand{\xauthA}{Nicola Casadei}
\newcommand{\xauthB}{Marco Benedetti}
\newcommand{\xauthC}{Erica Marchi}
\newcommand{\xauthD}{Mattia Ricci}
\newcommand{\xfaculty}{II Faculty Engineering and Informatic Science}
\newcommand{\xunibo}{Alma Mater Studiorum -- University of Bologna}
\newcommand{\xaddrCE}{via Sacchi 3}
\newcommand{\xcityCE}{47023 Cesena, Italy}

%
% Comments
%

%%% \newcommand{\todo}[1]{\bf{TODO:}\emph{#1}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{xpatch}



\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\authcount{\the\c@auco}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{author}{\toc@uthor}%
}{% Replace by 'nothing'
}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failed}}

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \if!\the\toctitle!\addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\@title}\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\the\toctitle}\fi
}{%
  % Replace by nothing
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed patching!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Esame finale A.A. 2016/2017\\
  Ingegneria dei Sistemi Software}

%%% \author{\xauthA \and \xauthB}
\author{\xauthA \\ \xauthB \\ \xauthC \\ \xauthD}

\institute{%
  %%% \xunibo\\\xaddrCE, \xcityCE\\\email{\{nameA.studentA, nameB.studentB\}@studio.unibo.it}
  \xunibo\\\xaddrCE, \xcityCE\\\email\ nameA.studentA@studio.unibo.it
}

\maketitle

% ==================INDEX
\newpage 
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Intro}
\labelsec{Intro}

\section{Vision}
\labelsec{Vision}

..... other sections

\end{document}
```

Comment: that you so much! this worked!